# SharpDX.XInput.dll (xinput1_4.dll): API is not supported for this application type

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, monogame

When I publish my app - Monogame-based XAML-app for Windows 8.1 app and Windows Phone 8.1 (universal app, two binaries) - certification fails:

> This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=XInputEnable. Module=xinput1_4.dll. File=SharpDX.XInput.dll.
>
> This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=XInputGetAudioDeviceIds. Module=xinput1_4.dll.
>   File=SharpDX.XInput.dll.
>
> This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=XInputGetBatteryInformation. Module=xinput1_4.dll.
>   File=SharpDX.XInput.dll.
>
> This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=XInputGetCapabilities. Module=xinput1_4.dll.
>   File=SharpDX.XInput.dll.
>
> This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=XInputGetKeystroke. Module=xinput1_4.dll. File=SharpDX.XInput.dll.
>
> This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=XInputGetState. Module=xinput1_4.dll. File=SharpDX.XInput.dll.
>
> This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=XInputSetState. Module=xinput1_4.dll. File=SharpDX.XInput.dll.
>
> This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=GetNativeSystemInfo. Module=kernel32.dll.
>   File=AdDuplex.Universal.Win.WinRT.winmd.

All these messages are about Windows 8.1 binary. I had apps with Monogame and AdDuplex before and everything was fine. Ok, even if I exclude AdDuplex there is SharpDX.XInput.dll, which is included in project implicitly (I didn't include it).

Just in case - in my app I include the following:

c:\Program Files (x86)\MonoGame\v3.0\Assemblies\Windows8\
MonoGame.Framework.dll
SharpDX.dll
SharpDX.Direct2D1.dll
SharpDX.Direct3D11.dll
SharpDX.DXGI.dll
SharpDX.MediaFoundation.dll
SharpDX.XAudio2.dll

App works ok in Win 8.1 and 10, but certification fails.
Tried dlls from c:\Program Files (x86)\MonoGame\v3.0\Assemblies\WindowsUniversal folder, but they target .net 5.0, while win8.1 app targets 4.5.1.

Is it possible to publish Monogame Windows 8.1 XAML app at all?

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case there were a simple solution. I use winrt lib for background processing, it is "portable", so I include Monogame for win8 xaml into it just to compile codebase. So I include this winmd into both win and wp projects and everything worked locally. But msft analyser found dll names and certification failed.

The solution was to make two "portable" libs, identical but in the second one I include Monogame for winphone 8.1.
Msft promised that you can use one project for both binaries, because it is portable (and it works, but msft would not accept this binary)! As always, msft docs are just a shame. And they even bought Monogame and Xamarin...